# How to make testng listeners runs before the @AfterClass annotation?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, appium, listener

Scenario - I have a listener which generates the report for the execution. I want to add the generated test report to database. I have a function in `@AfterClass` annotation which needs to add the generated report to database.

Problem I'm facing - Listener is generating the report only `@AfterClass` method gets executed.

Is there a way to make the listener generate the reports once the `@Test` annotation tests get executed and add the generated report to database in `@AfterClass` annotation?

Please let me know if there is any better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented your own test listener with `TestListenerAdapter`, you have methods `onStart`, `onFinish`, `onTestSuccess` and `onTestFailure`. So if you need to generate your report after each test, just put your logic inside these methods.

```
public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    //your logic for report generation
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext iTestContext) {
    //your logic for report generation
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    //your logic for report generation
    }
}
```

I don't know in what cases you should generate (and how) your report, but in accordance with your needs you can put your report logic in relevant methods.

Comment: Can you please share a example or documents to verify.

Comment: @user3782636 edited my answer. [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) is the docs about listeneres. [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.13/org/testng/TestListenerAdapter.html) doc regarding `TestListenerAdapter`

Comment: @user3782636 did it help?